# Outlook Web Add-in Category Issue

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an Issue with setting outlook categories.

I've tried to set the category of a mail, by using the [JS API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/categories) as well as by sending an EWS-Request.
Both approaches work on most mails, however, on some mails the category either is not beeing set or disappears after being set, even though I receive a success message from the API.

Some background infos regarding the enviroment:
Test Environment Version: Outlook 365 16.0.14326.20702 32-Bit
Hybrid Exchange Version: 15.1 (Build 2176.2)

The main logic would looks like this:

```
let getMasterCategories = async function (masterCategoriesToAdd) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Office.context.mailbox.masterCategories.getAsync(function (asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        console.log("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
        return reject(false);
      } else {
        const masterCategories = asyncResult.value;
        let categoryFound = false;
        console.log("Master categories:");
        masterCategories.forEach(function (item) {
          if (item.displayName == 'TestCat')
            categoryFound = true;
        });

        if (!categoryFound) {
          Office.context.mailbox.masterCategories.addAsync(masterCategoriesToAdd, function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
              console.log("Successfully added categories to master list");
              return resolve(true);
            } else {
              console.log("masterCategories.addAsync call failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
              return reject(false);
            }
          });
        }
        return resolve(true);
      }
    });
  });
};

let addCategory = async function (categoriesToAdd) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.categories.addAsync(categoriesToAdd, function (asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        console.log("Successfully added categories");
        return resolve(true);
      } else {
        console.log("categories.addAsync call failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
        return reject(false);
      }
    });
  });
};

Office.onReady((info) => {
  let masterCategoryToBeAdded = [{
    "displayName": "TestCat",
    "color": Office.MailboxEnums.CategoryColor.Preset0
  }];

  getMasterCategories(masterCategoryToBeAdded).then(function (succeeded) {
    if (succeeded) {
      addCategory(["TestCat"]);
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the issue happening for reading the messages in the inbox or are you composing a mail? Can you record a video of the issue happening?

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense try to call the [SaveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.appointmentcompose?view=outlook-js-1.4&preserve-view=true#outlook-office-appointmentcompose-saveasync-member(1)) method to make your changes permanent. If the issue still persists I'd suggest posting this as a bug to https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues.